# Dropwizard Path: Get all paths in app

Tags: java, dropwizard

Does anyone know how to get the same information, about what paths are used, like at the start of dw application. I mean the output after this line:

```
io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig: The following paths were found for the configured resources:
GET     /path/of/res/test (this.is.the.class.package.info.MyRessource)
POST     /path/of/res/test2 (this.is.the.class.package.info.MyRessource2)
```

I have to check if specific path exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works for me (DW 0.7.1):

```
private Multimap<String, String> getEndpoints(Environment environment)
{
    Multimap<String, String> resources = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    ResourceConfig jrConfig = environment.jersey().getResourceConfig();
    Set<Object> dwSingletons = jrConfig.getSingletons();

    for (Object singletons : dwSingletons) {        

        if (singletons.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) {                
            AbstractResource resource = IntrospectionModeller.createResource(singletons.getClass());
            AbstractResource superResource = IntrospectionModeller.createResource(singletons.getClass().getSuperclass());

            String uriPrefix = getStringWithoutStartingSlash(resource.getPath().getValue());

            for (AbstractResourceMethod srm :resource.getResourceMethods())
            {
                String uri = uriPrefix;
                resources.put(uri,srm.getHttpMethod());
                LOG.info("Found http method " +srm.getHttpMethod() + " for the path " + uri + " returning (class) " + srm.getReturnType().getName());
            }


            for (AbstractSubResourceMethod srm :resource.getSubResourceMethods())
            {           
                //extended resources methods will be added by hand
                if(superResource != null){
                    for (AbstractSubResourceMethod superSrm : superResource.getSubResourceMethods())
                    {
                        String srmPath = getStringWithoutStartingSlash(srm.getPath().getValue());
                        String superSrmPath = getStringWithoutStartingSlash(superSrm.getPath().getValue());                     

                        Class<?> srmClass = srm.getDeclaringResource().getResourceClass();
                        Class<?> superSrmClass = superSrm.getDeclaringResource().getResourceClass();

                        //add superclass method if methodName is not equal superMethodName
                        if(srmClass.getSuperclass().equals(superSrmClass) && !srm.getMethod().getName().equals(superSrm.getMethod().getName())){
                            String uri = uriPrefix + "/" + srmPath  + "/" + superSrmPath ;                              
                            resources.put(uri,superSrm.getHttpMethod());
                            LOG.info("Found http method " +superSrm.getHttpMethod() + " for the path " + uri + " returning (class) " + superSrm.getReturnType().getName());
                        }   
                    }
                }

                String uri = uriPrefix + "/" + getStringWithoutStartingSlash(srm.getPath().getValue());
                resources.put(uri,srm.getHttpMethod());
                LOG.info("Found http method " +srm.getHttpMethod() + " for the path " + uri + " returning (class) " + srm.getReturnType().getName());           
            }               
        }
    }        
    return resources;
    }
```

But @PathParam annoations are also plain, e.g. if @Path("/{id}") then sth. like '.../{id}' will be used!!!

If you extend your resources and super class does also have path annotation, then this method will produce also informations and even more than the default DW logEndpoints() method!

FYI: The imports used in class

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.model.AbstractResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.model.AbstractResourceMethod;
import com.sun.jersey.api.model.AbstractSubResourceMethod;
import com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;  
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to do this on your own. Take a look at the [`logEndpoints` method](http://goo.gl/sOcXMc) (which is what actually logs this information - with private methods). You should be able to adapt this method to handle the resources from your `environment.jersey().getResourceConfig()` after you configure your resources in your `run` method.

Something like:

```java
final ImmutableList.Builder<Class<?>> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
for (Object o : environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getSingletons()) {
  if (o.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) {
    builder.add(o.getClass());
  }
}
for (Class<?> klass : environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getClasses()) {
  if (klass.isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) {
    builder.add(klass);
  }
}
final List<String> endpoints = Lists.newArrayList();
for (Class<?> klass : builder.build()) {
  AbstractResource resource = IntrospectionModeller.createResource(klass);
  endpoints.add(resource.getPath().getValue());
}
```

Note that what's in master is slightly ahead of what's in Maven - the above example shows how to get the `AbstractResource` which will work with 0.7.1. You'll have to be sure to adapt your method as dropwizard evolves. This example also doesn't normalize the path but I you can easily add that based on `logEndpoints`.

Comment: This code does not contain any path of extended resources, nor paths of class methods!

Answer (score 2):

I used a simpler approach for getting the same data. All the resources here are jersey resources.

```
 Map<String, Object> beansWithAnnotation = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class);

    Collection<Object> values = beansWithAnnotation.values();
    for (Object next : values) {
            ResourceUtil.getResourceUrls(next);
    }


public static List<String> getResourceUrls(Object obj)
{
    Resource resource = Resource.from(obj.getClass());
    String uriPrefix = resource.getPath();
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Resource res :resource.getChildResources())
    {
        String uri = uriPrefix + res.getPath();
        urls.add(uri);
    }
    return urls;
}
```